# Why so many Tate groups?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Here is a question to anyone who knows Class Field Theory. Why do we define Tate groups for all integers but only end up using $H_{T}^i$ for $i \in$ {-1,0}? Sure, sometimes we consider the case when i is 1, 2 or -2 but it seems like we don't really use the other ones. Is there a simpler way to understand, or get the essential information from, these important first few groups without looking at them as terms in a long exact sequence?

Comment: Why do we consider the set of natural numbers when, most of the time, we can do with those up to 100? Or $10^{100}$?

Comment: False analogy. Restricting our construction of integers to values under 10^100 does not actually simplify anything. In fact, it could actually make things more complicated. If we limit our construction of the Tate groups to the ones that we use and limit the introduction of general facts that hold for all Tate groups, we actually do get a presentation that is in a way simpler for the purposes of CFT. In fact, Neukirch precisely does this in his algebraic number theory book. His abstract class field theory only requires knowledge of |H_0| and |H_1| and he does not even define all Tate groups.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give any precision on what you call the Tate groups $H_i^T$, but I suppose that you speak of the "modified" cohomology groups $\hat H^i(G, .)$ of a finite group $G$ ? Actually they are defined by $\hat H^i(G,A)= H^i(G,A)$ if $i\ge 1$, $\hat H^0(G,A)=A^G/NA$ if $i=0$ and $\hat H_{-n}(G, A)=H_{n-1}(G,A)$ if $\ge2$. Here $A^G=H^0(G,A)$ (the $G$-invariants points) and the $H_{n-1}(G,A)$ are the homology groups. Moreover, the norm $N$ induces a map $N^*:H_{0} (G,A) \to H^0(G,A)$,  we have $\hat H^{0}(G, A)=Coker N^*$, and we put $\hat H^{-1}(G, A)=Ker N^*$ . From these definitions we can construct naturally a *cohomological functor* in all dimensions, which allows to derive from any exact sequence of $G$-modules $0\to A \to B \to C \to 0$ an infinite  exact sequence of modified cohomology groups $...\hat H^q(G, A) \to \hat H^q(G, B) \to \hat H^q(G, C)\to \hat H^{q+1}(G, A) \to ...$ For technical details, see e.g. Cassels-Fröhlich, ANT, IV,6. Roughly speaking, starting from the homological and cohomological functors in positive dimensions, we glue them together by means of the modified  $\hat H^{-1}$ and $\hat H^{0}$ .